# Linked list arrow operator

Tags: c++, c, pointers, linked-list

In a basic linked list program, this I usually implement it:

```
struct node {
    int info;
    struct node * next;
};

int main() {
    struct node * head = malloc(sizeof(node)*3); //for 3 nodes
    head->info = 1;
    head->next->info = 2;
    head->next->next->info = 3;
    //more code
}
```

Now, to print the contents of the second node, I use the following statement:

```
cout<<head->next->info;
```

My question is, instead of using the above statement, can the following be used:

```
cout<<head[1]->info;
```

Comment: `this I usually implement it`. You should never implement it. You should use `std::list`.

Comment: BTW your code is completely wrong - your `next` pointers are all uninitialised. Linked lists are not supposed to be contiguous blocks of elements anyway.

Comment: In your implementation above you never set the value of `head->next` or any of it's children. This will most likely cause an exception when you try and dereference the uninitialised pointers.

Comment: Interesting combination of linked list and array.

Comment: To be clear, the "exception" @Will talks about is not a C++ exception, but an OS memory exception.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, instead of using the above statement, can the following be used:
>
> ```
> cout<<head[1]->info;
> ```

In your case, actually, *yes*, because your code does not create a linked list but more like an array. An array where each element is apparently supposed to have a pointer `next` to the next element, but all these pointers are uninitialised.

Use `std::list` until you know how a linked list works... and then keep using it anyway!

Comment: I would tell him/her: **Learn** how a linked list works first, and then start and keep using `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list is meant to have elements which aren't contiguous in memory. The format head[1] requires contiguous elements.

Anyway the code in your example doesn't represent a linked list

Answer (score 0):

NO.head is a pointer and head[1] means *(head+1),but in your list,each list node is not adjacent .Usually,list can't do this unless you put each node one by one with adjacent address

PS. sorry for my poor English

Comment: In his "list", each node _is_ adjacent.